# Can I attach multiple transformers/processors to a single stream in Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

In all example I see a simple single transformer/processor topology for Kafka. My doubt is whether we can modularise application logic by breaking down in to multiple transformers/processors applying sequentially to a single input stream.

Please find use case below :

Current application configuration is a single processor containing all processing logic tasks like filtering, validation, application logic, delaying(Kafka is too fast for dbs) and invoke SP/push to down stream.

But we are now planning to decouple all these operations by breaking down each task into separate processors/transformers of Kstream.

Since we are relatively new to Kafka, we are not sure of the pros and cons of this approach especially with respect to Kafka internals like state store/ task scheduling/ multithreading model.

Please share your expert opinions and experiences
**Please note that we do not have control over topic, no new topic can be created for this design. The design must be feasible for the existing topic alone.**

[image]

Comment: A heads up if you do not own or may create new topics in the cluster is that streams may not work since it creates internal topics: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/manage-topics.html#internal-topics

Answer (score 1):

Kafka Streams allows you to split your logic into multiple processors. Internally, Kafka Streams implements a "depth-first" execution strategy. Thus, each time you call "forward" the output tuple is immediately processed by the downstream processor and "forward" return after downstream processing finished (note, that writing data into a topic and reading it back "breaks" the in-memory pipeline -- thus, when data is written to a topic, there is no guarantee when downstream processor will read and process those records).

If you have state that is shared between multiple processor, you would need to attach the store to all processor that need to access to store. The execution on the store will be single threaded and thus, there should be no performance difference.

As long as you connect processor directly (and not via topics) all processor will be part of the same tasks. Thus, there shouldn't be a performance difference.

Comment: Thanks @Matthias, I will try out and let you know my findings